# How to check if a relationship exists in a Django template?

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a Django project where a user can re post other users posts by creating a relationship between the user and the post itself. But when I display this on my template, I want the tweets that have been re posted to have a different link next to them in order to un repost but instead with my current set up it still has the re post link, so I was just wondering how I could see if a relationship exists in a Django template as part of my conditional.

template

```
            {% for tweets in combined_tweets %}
               <p>{{ tweets.userprofile.user}} | {{ tweets }} | {{ tweets.date }} |
            {% if tweets.userprofile.user == request.user %}
               <a href='{% url "delete_tweet" request.user.id tweets.id %}'>DELETE</a>
            {% elif ###Something to check if realtionship exists### %}
                UN REPOST LINK
            {% else %}
               <a href='{% url "retweet" tweets.id %}'>RETWEET</a>
            {% endif %}</p>
            {% endfor %}
```

models.py

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
  user = models.OneToOneField(User)
  bio = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True, verbose_name='Biography')
  follows = models.ManyToManyField('self', related_name='followers', symmetrical=False, blank=True)
  theme = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_image_path, blank=True)
  profile_picture = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_image_path, blank=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.bio

class Tweet(models.Model):
  userprofile = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile)
  retweet = models.ManyToManyField(UserProfile, related_name='retweet_people', symmetrical=False, blank=True)
  tweets = models.TextField(max_length=120)
  date = models.DateTimeField()
```

Comment: Please post your models.

Comment: I think this line: `{% if tweets.userprofile.user == request.user %}` should be `{% if tweets.userprofile.user == user %}`

Comment: Yes that will work but I do not need that fixed it works fine.

Comment: Have you tried `{% elif tweet.retweet %}`.  (I'm assuming that's the relationship you're concerned with. It's hard to tell.)

Comment: yes that would see if it has any relationship at all, but I want to see if the logged in user is in a relationship with that specific post not just if the post has a relationship in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can check that a relationship exists between the current user and other user `tweets` using a [custom template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters).**

We will write a custom template filter `check_relationship_exists` which will take the current user as the argument. This will check if the current tweet object is related to the user passed by performing a filter on its `retweet` attribute using `user.id`. If there exists a relationship, then the `UN REPOST` link will be displayed otherwise a `RETWEET` link will be shown.

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.filter(name='check_relationship_exists')
def check_relationship_exists(tweet_object, user):
    user_id = int(user.id) # get the user id
    return tweet_object.retweet.filter(id=user_id).exists() # check if relationship exists
```

Then in your template, you can do the following:

```
{% elif tweets|check_relationship_exists:request.user %}
```

Comment: Funny I actually looked at these, but you put it all together for me.